# Bash Script Unstable Result

Tags: linux, bash, unix, cron

I have bash script and I put in the crontab. It runs every 10 minutes. When I run it manually, it gives perfect results. It creates ".tmp" files and these ".tmp" files are not empty, but Crontab results are not as I expected. it only creates ".tmp" files. Contents of ".tmp" files are empty. In this computer there more than one user. Could it be user privilege issue? What could be the main reason?

Thanks in advance..

Sorry, I forgot :) my code.

```
export GGATE=/ggate/ggs11g
alias gate='clear;cd $GGATE;./ggsci'
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/dbhome_1
export ORACLE_SID=KNNPRO17_1
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:${GGS_HOME}
export LIBPATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:$GGS_HOME:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME:$ORACLE_HOME/lib:$GGS_HOME

MYGGSCI=$GGATE/ggsci
LOGDIR=$GGATE/scripts/logs
GGSLAGFILE01=${LOGDIR}/ggslagfile01.tmp
GGSLAGFILE02=${LOGDIR}/ggslagfile02.tmp
GGSLAG_EMAIL=${LOGDIR}/ggslag_email.tmp

$MYGGSCI << eof > $GGSLAGFILE01
info all
eof

cat $GGSLAGFILE01 | egrep -i '(EXTRACT)'|cut -d":" -f 1,2,3,4,5,6 | tr ":" " "|tr -s '[:space:]'|cut -d" " -f1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 >$GGSLAGFILE02

awk '{if ( $4 > 00 || $5 >=30 || $7 > 00 || $8 >=30 ) {print $1 " " $3 " HAS LAG of " $4" hour " $5 " min for checkpoint " $7 " hour " $8 " min -- at -- " d "\n" }}' d="$(date)" $GGSLAGFILE02 > $GGSLAG_EMAIL

if [ -s $GGSLAG_EMAIL ]
  then
    mailx -s "${ORACLE_SID} Extract LAG ! on GoldenGate" "it.io.db.goldengate@vodafone.com" < $GGSLAG_EMAIL
    exit 1
  else
    exit 0
fi
```

and

my crontab is

00,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * ksh /export/GoldenGate/scripts/check.sh 2>/dev/null

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Crontab jobs should assume no particular environment. Use absolute paths for all files and executables at the crontab file (give full path to `ksh`). For scripts you may set the `PATH` variable to a safe default and then use `cd` to ensure a correct working directory. Also, make sure all files are relative to the set working directory or have absolute paths.

Comment: And why do you throw away stderr? Cron would have mailed you the problem right in your inbox.

Comment: Don't use aliases in a script; use a function. `gate () { clear; cd "$GGATE"; .ggsci; }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that your:

```
/ggate/ggs11g/ggsci
```

which you call from

```
$MYGGSCI
```

requires some environment variables from the user you are running it as. 
To see if this is the issue, please modify the crontab entry like so:

```
00,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * . $HOME/.bashrc; /bin/ksh /export/GoldenGate/scripts/check.sh 2>/dev/null
```

The

```
. $HOME/.bashrc;
```

sources the environment variables from your ".bashrc" file.

Comment: Throwing away stderr (in a crontab of all files) is a good way to find yourself in the dark.

Comment: Thank you @AnythingIsFine. What is your solution @Jens?

Comment: @Jens whas suggesting that you may find out what is not working in crontab by saving the stderr output to a file to review post execution as so:  00,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * . $HOME/.bashrc; /bin/ksh /export/GoldenGate/scripts/check.sh >> /tmp/crontab_test.txt 2>&1